# elasticseach 6 scroll,second fetch impossible

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll

I use es 6.3.2.I want to fetch documents using scroll.Use postman to test:
first,I create an index:

```
PUT /person4 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6d98c502-d37b-4798-adc8-2fb1f31f228f
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

then insert some documents:

```
POST /person4/type1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 70f2167e-280f-444c-b588-d034c8a55a5c

{
    "lastname":"alex"
}
```

repeat this post for many times.

follow this instruction:[web](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)
Then use scroll api first time:

```
 POST /person4/_search?scroll=1s HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6d92fbb8-c861-434f-bf31-3023ff1fb282

{
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "lastname" : "alex"
        }
    }
}
```

Then got 1 document and the scroll id

Finally,second fetch:

```
POST /person4/_search/scroll HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 14238262-6125-4f60-8025-d0d2854b8dd6

{
    "scroll" : "1s", 
    "scroll_id" : "DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoBQAAAAAAAABIFklhQmdpTWVOUTVxbkFTM1l6U1dpRHcAAAAAAAAAShZJYUJnaU1lTlE1cW5BUzNZelNXaUR3AAAAAAAAAEkWSWFCZ2lNZU5RNXFuQVMzWXpTV2lEdwAAAAAAAABHFklhQmdpTWVOUTVxbkFTM1l6U1dpRHcAAAAAAAAASxZJYUJnaU1lTlE1cW5BUzNZelNXaUR3" 
}
```

Then got an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
                "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_search]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
        "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_search]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

So I have to add the type:

```
POST /person4/_search/type1/scroll HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 43c8052f-76c9-41b9-a0a6-637eb5fee30b

{
    "scroll" : "1s", 
    "scroll_id" : "DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoBQAAAAAAAABIFklhQmdpTWVOUTVxbkFTM1l6U1dpRHcAAAAAAAAAShZJYUJnaU1lTlE1cW5BUzNZelNXaUR3AAAAAAAAAEkWSWFCZ2lNZU5RNXFuQVMzWXpTV2lEdwAAAAAAAABHFklhQmdpTWVOUTVxbkFTM1l6U1dpRHcAAAAAAAAASxZJYUJnaU1lTlE1cW5BUzNZelNXaUR3" 
}
```

Then I got an new error:

```
{
    "error": "no handler found for uri [/person4/_search/type1/scroll] and method [POST]"
}
```

So how to fetch more document?Can only fetch for one time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your second fetch has index name in the request URL. [The URL should not include the index or type name — these are specified in the original search request instead.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#CO47-2)

Instead of this:

```
POST /person4/_search/scroll HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 14238262-6125-4f60-8025-d0d2854b8dd6

{
    "scroll" : "1s", 
    "scroll_id" : "Whatever scroll id you've got" 
}
```

Use this:

```
POST /_search/scroll HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 14238262-6125-4f60-8025-d0d2854b8dd6

{
    "scroll" : "1s", 
    "scroll_id" : "Whatever scroll id you've got" 
}
```